# Stretched view under TableView cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I have View, under cells (with static heights) of TableViewController . I want to stratch view.

How i can do that?[image: Stretched view under TableView cells]

---

P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: you can set it with `view.frame`

Comment: Which image is the wanted one?

Comment: "View" is subview of TableViewController

Comment: I need to stretch "View"

Comment: I need to do like on the second image (right, after arrow)

Comment: You can set a `NSLayoutConstraint` setting the that the top of the view is the bottom of the tableview.